# Adding Column on table row with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have searching and trying some code for adding cols on table rows, here is my full code:

```
<!doctype htlm>
<html>
<head>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function addCols2(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').find('tr').each(function(){
        $(this).find('td').eq(6).after('<td>col 8</td>');
    });
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" border =1>
<?php

for($x=0;$x<5;$x++){
echo '<tr><td class=TableHeading>column 1</td>
        <td class=TableHeading>column 2</td>
        <td class=TableHeading>column 3</td>
    <td class=TableHeading>column 4</td>
    <td class=TableHeading>column 5</td>
    <td class=TableHeading>column 6</td>
    <td class=TableHeading>column 7</td>
<script type="text/javascript">
  addCols2();
 </script>
</tr>';
}

?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

but when I check the display, every row have 5 (according to looping) col 8 (that I added).
Can someone tell me where is the code wrong?

Comment: put the document ready above the function declaration

Comment: move the script calling `addCols2()` out of the php loop if your jquery is already doing the `each` loop

Comment: very big thanks to theshadowmonkey, it solved :D